# Is the condition that two manifolds share a (n-1)-manifold necessary to obtain that the union is also a manifold?

Tags: manifolds

I looked on the site but I did not find anything matching my problem.

I am working in 4D with cubical complexes, also known as Khalimsky grids; I mean that I work with "cubical" manifolds.

Do you know if it is possible that, starting from two topological 4-manifolds A and B, the union of A and B is a 4-manifold too, even if the intersection of A and B is the union of two 3D cubes which share a vertex, that is, even if the shared space between the two manifolds is not a 3-manifold ?

I heard about "connected sums" of manifolds which preserve manifoldness, however the intersection of my two manifolds here is not a manifold itself.

Thank you in advance guys, I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific : Are you assuming that your manifolds are compact? Do you allow manifolds to have boundary?

Comment: Effectively, the two 4-manifolds A and B are made of a finite number of 4D unitary cubes, and then they are compact 4-manifolds with a compact boundary.

Comment: The answer is that $A\cup_C B$ is a manifold (possibly with boundary) (in your setting) if and only if $C$ is a submanifold (possibly with boundary) of both $\partial A$ and of $\partial B$, or if $C$ equals a connected component of either $A$ or of $B$. In particular, $C$ has to be a manifold (possibly with boundary). The proof of necessity is based on some local homology computations; I do not sure how comfortable you are with homology groups.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It helps me a lot ! Do you have any reference or any book with proves this theorem ? And can you tell me more about this proof, I'm not very confortable with homology groups but I'm learning homology with the book of Computational homology of Kaczynski et al. :)

Comment: There is no textbook reference I am aware of; I will write a proof when I have more time.

Comment: Or perhaps could you advise me a reference in matter of homology related to manifolds that you know? I can start to (try to) think about the proof by myself.

Comment: Since you never worked with homology, I doubt it, but just in case: The homological condition for a space $M$ to be an $n$-dimensional manifold (possibly with boundary) is that for every $x\in M$ (not on the potential boundary) $H_k(M,M-\{x\})$ is isomorphic to ${\mathbb Z}$ for $k=n$ and zero otherwise. In your case, you would be computing homology using the Mayer-Vietoris long exact sequence (with respect to the decomposition of $M$ as the union of two manifolds with boundary $M_1, M_2$).

Comment: Thank you so much Moishe :)